# Website does not update - Even after Invalidation through AWS Website, CLI and changing metadata of S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am having a problem that I can't find a solution to, despite numerous online resources indicating ways to do what I want.

I have made a change to the index (filename: harryleeceinfo.html) of my website, which I see successfully reflected when I open the object URL from S3 for the index page.  Now, my understanding is that I must invalidate the index page through cloudfront, where my website is cached.  I invalidate the index page as follows:
[image: invalidation of index attempt]
And waited 30 minutes to no avail.

Next I tried the aws cli, using the command:

`aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id E329EH7Q22XQ04 --paths /harrisonleeceinfo.html`

Again I waited 30 mins and saw no change to the website, and went to bed to see if it would be updated in the morning.  It was not.

This morning I went to S3 and selected the whole bucket and changed the metadata Cache-Control value to 300 and waited 30 mins again, and still see no change to the website.

What could possibly be the problem here?  Is this a caching issue or could I simply have failed to update s3 in the correct ways?

Please let me know your thoughts

-Harrison

Comment: Have you validated it is not cached in your browser rather than CloudFront caching it?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I cleared Cache on Firefox and also viewed the site with my phone.  No change to the contents of the site.

Comment: When you invalidate the cache (and it clears) can you check the `x-cache` header for whether it shows either `Hit` or `Miss`?

Comment: try invalidate using `/*`